# Verify $H_2(x) = 4x^2-2$ satisfies Hermite differential equation.

Tags: special-functions, hermite-polynomials

I am slightly confused by the meaning of the question:

**Q.** The differential equation obeyed by Hermite polynomial is

$$y''-2xy'+2ny=0$$

a) Use the Rodrigues' formula for Hermite polynomial

$$H_n(x)=(-1)^n e^{x^2}\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2}$$

to find $H_2(x)$ and verify that it satisfies the above differential equation.

So by doing this I got $H_2(x) = 4x^2-2$. But what dose it mean by verify? How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
H_2(x)=\color{orange}{4x^2-2} \\
H_2'=\color{red}{8x} \\
H_2''=\color{purple}{8} .
\end{eqnarray*}
Substitute into $y''-2xy'+2ny$ and verify that it gives zero,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\color{purple}{8} -2x(\color{red}{8x} )+2\times 2( \color{orange}{4x^2-2}) =0.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Ah well that alot eaiser. I was under the impression I had to take the general case somehow.